# Return values from thread Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have a multiclient server setup like this.This piece of code works fine but what if i need to return the messages from handle_client to main and store them without using a global variable ?

Server Side

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)
def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
            conn.send("Msg received".encode(FORMAT))

    conn.close()
    

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")

print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

And on the client side

```
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))

send("Hello World!")
input()
send("Hello Everyone!")

send(DISCONNECT_MESSAGE)
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: When you say "return to main" what does that actually mean?

Comment: Imagine that 3 clients will connect so i want to return 3 messages in a list

Comment: But your clients may connect far apart in time, so that's one message three times. What will `main` do with these messages?

Comment: FYI, consider that `recv(n)` returns 1 to n bytes or 0 on disconnect.  `recv(n)` is *not* guaranteed to return exactly `n` bytes.  Under the right network conditions this code could fail. `send()` has a similar issue.  Consider `sendall()` at least.

Comment: @ThodorisSamaras Is that possible? What if a 4th client connects but it's too late because the list was already "returned to main"? Should it wait to see if a 4th client connects? How long should it wait? And it also doesn't really explain the words "return to main".

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a thread-safe `queue` that the `handle_client` function takes as a parameter and can push items on when it needs to.
There will need to be another thread taking items off, but this could be the main thread. In that case you would need yet another thread which blocks on `server.accept()` waiting to start new `handle_client` threads.

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps the safest way to send data from one thread to another is to use a Queue from the queue library. To do this, create a Queue instance that is shared by the threads. Threads then use put() or get() operations to add or remove items from the queue as shown in the code given below.

See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-communicating-between-threads-set-1/#:%7E:text=Perhaps%20the%20safest%20way%20to,in%20the%20code%20given%20below.) for example.